¿como hacer que los marcadores de folium no aumente su tamaño cuando reduzco el zoom?
Esto ubicando ciertas posiciones en un mapa de folium, sin embargo, los marcadores cuando ejecuto el código se muestran de un tamaño, y a medida que voy aumentando el zoom del mapa estos se van reduciendo.


folium.RegularPolygonMarker(location=[ct['LATITUD'], ct['LONGITUD']],
fill_color=color_hex,color=color_hex,fill=True,fill_opacity=1,
number_of_sides=3,radius=7,rotation=45,weight=0.2,
popup=folium.Popup(popup_html, max_width=500)).add_to(transformer_layer)

